# No muestra el calendario ,el modulo mat-datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, modulos

Tengo este codigo en Angular y utilice el componente de input datapicker,cuando corro el programa este muestra el input pero no me desplega el cuadro con las fechas para ajustar con el mouse ,eh revisado todo y nada

```html
 <div class="row">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline" >
        <mat-label>Escoge la fecha</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="fecha">
        <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker">
          <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        </mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
imports:[
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule
  ]
```

```html
 import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

 imports: [MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
  ],
```

El error que me muestra error TS2339: Property 'Matpicker' does not exist on type 'Observable

Comment: Agrega el código que falta para ver  donde esta el problema.

Comment: Agrega toda la traza del error que te de el navegador. Parece que estás poniendo una sección de tu componente unicamente. Entonces, estas importando dos veces tus modulos, uno app.module, y otro en el componente. Desde la v16 de angular existe la propiedad en el injector del componente "standalone" que permite utilizar el componente como un modulo por si mismo, pero en tu caso, no estás utilizando esta propiedad. Si copiaste un ejemplo desde la página oficial de angular material, posiblemente tengasa que agregar esa propiedad.